# Read PDF in a folder blocked by .htaccess and display in html

Tags: php, html, security, pdf

I have question about reading PDF in the folder where is blocked for security reason. I want to display in admin page but since it is blocked by .htaccess, I have to find alternative way to display it

I tried to read it using readfile or getcontent using ajax and put in  but it does not show.

```
function getContractFile($file)
{
    echo readfile($file)
}
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url:"xxx/getContractFile",
    type:"post",
    data:{
        file:file
    },
    function(data){
         $('#fileWin').html('<embed src="'+data+'">')
    }
})
```

Question 1 
how can i insert it in  ?

Question2
is there better way to solve this problem that the file is in the folder which is blocked by ,htaccess (Deny from all) and show the file in admin side?